# Convert grid in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, grid

Problem is I have list item product be ordered follow:
[image]

Now,I want to convert list above to grid follow:

[image]

Using Jquery+HTML+CSS. How to I convert it. Can anyone help me. Thanks pro

Answer (score 0):

Create inline-block divs with you numbers inside of them.

```css
.col{
  display:inline-block; 
}
.col div{
  border:2px solid black;
  width:50px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="col">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
<div class="col">
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
</div>
<div class="col">
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
  <div>11</div>
  <div>12</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I in this situation, I want using PHP loop to create item. Can you help me define loop.